# наибольшая средняя стоимость

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы, имеют следующий вид

```
CREATE TABLE company (
    companyId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    companyName VARCHAR (50),
    companyCountry VARCHAR (50)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE phone
(
    phoneId serial PRIMARY KEY,
    phoneModel VARCHAR (50),
    companyId INTEGER REFERENCES company(companyId),
    price NUMERIC 
);
```

составить запросы поиска производителя телефона с наибольшей средней стоимостью телефона этого производителя;

Вот что получилось на данный момент, дальше пока не догоню, как писать(

```
SELECT companyname, price, phonemodel
  FROM phone
  LEFT JOIN company ON 
    company.companyid = phone.companyid
```

Comment: Читать про группировку и агрегатные функции

Comment: Вообще, вопрос выглядит как "типичный вопрос с собеседования по SQL". Это не говорит о том, что вопрос хороший или плохой, просто выглядит знакомо

Comment: @S.H., больше похоже на вопрос с зачёта после первого полугодия изучения SQL

Answer (score 0):

Ну почитать про group  by можно, например, тут - https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/4.6.php.

А вот запрос:

```
SELECT companyName, avg(price) 
FROM phone 
LEFT JOIN company ON phone.companyId = company.companyId 
GROUP BY company.companyId;
```